# Should it be "IS" or "ARE"? --- "The only thing we haven't seen ARE locusts."

Tags: grammar, auxiliary-verbs

This is from an article published on CNBC:

"**The only thing we haven't seen are locusts,** said CEO Jim McCann in an interview." [CNBC-A rose is still a rose](https://www.cnbc.com/2015/02/13/for-1-800-flowers-a-rose-is-still-a-rose-all-year-round.html)

The subject of the sentence is **"The only thing"**, which is clearly singular. So, **the auxiliary verb** must be **singular**, too. At least this is what we have been taught at school :)

However, you see in this sentence that the auxiliary is actually an **"ARE"**. **"The only thing.....are......"**.

If it is because it is followed by **"locusts"**, the word **"locusts"** is **not the subject** of the sentence. So, I, as a non-native English speaker, would expect the auxiliary verb should agree with the **subject**. However, apparently, it is not.

So, why is **"The only thing ..........."** being followed by an **"ARE"**?

Comment: The verb must always follow the subject, which is 'the only thing' (singular).

Comment: It's likely just an error. People do make mistakes. Not everybody is perfect.   Also are you relying on subtitles, or a transcription, or could you have misheard it? The verb agreement must be with the subject.  The only thing (singular) ... is.  The only things (plural) ... are.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a simple mistake, or a possibly a transcript error.

Comment: Just as we cannot hold people to literary standards in their everyday speech, we cannot use their spoken words as models of the written word. "Yeah" is a normal thing to say in conversation, whether judged as a whole sentence or not.

Comment: Locusts are the only thing we haven't seen.  This is called an inverse copular construction, which exists in English. See Wikipedia.

Comment: @BillyKerr There is no mistake  here. And there is disagreement among linguists about how to classify copular and inverse copular constructions.

Comment: It's not inverse. It's called the 'reversible specifying construction' because it has the _potential_ for the subject and PC to be reversed.

Comment: @BillJ Of course, but it can only be *shown comparatively*, not on its own. Ergo, if you cite both, they are reversed. Anyway, which came first, the chicken or the egg? The plumber is Fred. Fred is the plumber. QED.

Comment: The problem is the mismatch between singular subject "thing" and plural PC "locusts". Whichever verb is used results in a lack of number agreement between subject and predicator. Consider "The only **thing** we need now is new **curtains**, which is acceptable despite the mismatch.

Comment: @Lambie No: the term 'inverse' is wrong for the reason I gave, i.e. such specifying clauses with "be" have the **potential** to be reversed. That is why the term 'revsers**ible**', not 'inverse' is correct

Comment: @BillJ That is not how you show it. "a type of inversion in English where canonical SCP word order (subject-copula-predicative expression, e.g. Fred is the plumber) *is reversed in a sense*, so that one appears to have the order PCS instead (predicative expression-copula-subject, e.g. The plumber is Fred)." You show it by doing it.

Comment: @LAmbie. Yes, that is how it's described. Neither order is more correct than the other, hence the term 'reversible' since either order has the _potential_ to be reversed, thus reversing the functions.

Comment: @BillJ I repeat: **you can only show it by doing it**. Sure, reversible and once reversed, it is the inverse of the other. A learner will not get it otherwise and I daresay many others. In the absolute, which came first depends on which, in fact, was said or written first.

Comment: That _is_ the way it is described. Compare "Max was the guy who was arrested". Here "Max" is subject and "the guy ..." is PC. But in "The guy who was arrested was Max", the subject is "the guy ..." and "Max" is PC. Neither is more 'correct' than the other, neither is the inverse of the other, hence the term 'reversible'. since in a specifying construction like this with "be" either has the _potential_ to be reversed. Look up the meaning of the word "potential".

Comment: And in the OP's example "The only thing we haven't seen" is subject and "locusts" is PC. It has the _potential_ to be reversed to "Locusts are the only thing we haven't seen", where "locusts" functions as subject and "the only thing" as PC. Again both are correct. Either version has the _potential_ to be reversed. This is why the term 'reversible specifying construction" is preferable to "inverse copular construction'

Comment: Further, the ascriptive copular construction (as opposed to the specifying type) cannot be reversed without a change of functions, which is why we need the component "specifying" in the  title of the construction.

Comment: Yunus, please weigh in.  I don't think this should be closed.

Comment: @BillyKerr, no I am not relying on my mishearing, nor subtitles. This is from a text published on https://www.cnbc.com/2015/02/13/for-1-800-flowers-a-rose-is-still-a-rose-all-year-round.html

Comment: @BillyKerr Even if it's true that this is simply a mistake, the OP and others who might read this question later don't know that. That's the whole point of the question: He's asking whether this is correct or a mistake.

Comment: @Jay, yes exactly that.  Even it is a mistake of the speaker, a non-native speaker can't recognise that. Becase sometimes what you see as a mistake turns out to be not a mistake but a colloquial usage, dialect, non-standard use, etc., similarly some other times what you see is grammatically  correct turns out to be NOT idiomatic. So, learners have no other chance other than asking when they see something different from what they were taught at school.

Comment: Sorry to say that you have chosen an incorrect answer. I don't say that because I have an answer of my own - I made my answer *because* the accepted one is so misleadingly incorrect. And this is a binary choice, so it isn't just a little bit wrong - it is completely and utterly incorrect.

Comment: Is [this Q&A](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/29140/186210) related?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IS or ARE? "The only thing that I want you to hit right now IS/ARE the books"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/is-or-are-the-only-thing-that-i-want-you-to-hit-right-now-is-are-the-books)

Comment: @Astralbee, My choice is not final yet, and it may change as I continue to get scientifc and persuading examples. There are different views on that by other native English speakers, so it is not possible for me to say the "...ARE..." usage is totally and bluntly wrong, when it has a scientifc explanation on Wikipedia and there are also other examples by other native speakers. So currently it seems that both "..IS.." and "...ARE..." used, with "...IS.." being more common. However, I am still researching, because new resources are emerging as I read.

Comment: @Yunus - just because it has been published, doesn't mean it is correct.  Transcripts or quotes from interviews are generally written verbatim, warts and all. The things people say are not always grammatical. People can and do slip up.

Comment: I think this is one of those cases in which the insertion of some words between subject and verb obscures the relationships between the parts of the sentence and causes native speakers to become erratic. There would be no such confusion about the sentence, "*The only thing are locusts."

Comment: @Yunus I've added some examples from published books,  - published by academic university presses and other reputable academic publishers - for you to explore.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Locusts might be plural, but '*thing*' is the subject, and that is singular, so you should use **is**:

> The **only thing** we haven't seen **is** locusts.

There must be subject-verb agreement. The subject is singular, so the verb form (in this case, is/are are forms of the verb *to be*) must match that.

Plural nouns, like 'locusts' can often be used as *the generic plural* to refer to that thing in general, or as a collected group.

Example:

- My favourite fruit is bananas.
- My biggest fear is spiders.

In these examples, 'bananas' and 'spiders' represent *all* bananas and spiders in general. It would be ridiculous to say "my favourite fruit is *a banana*" - it would sound like you have one special banana that you love. Likewise, in your example, 'locusts' means the insect in general, not any specific group of locusts, which is why they can be referred to as the singular 'thing' that has not been seen.

It is true that, sometimes, the verb can agree with the individuals of a group even when the group is the subject but normally only when both are named and only to emphasise the individuality of the group members. And of course, even native speakers make mistakes. So don't be misled by Google results that show the contrary. Google the phrase "the only thing is" and the erroneous "the only thing are", and you will get results for both - however, the first will get you 49,300,000 results, the first of which is a dictionary definition of the phrase; the second, wrong phrase, gets you 1,140,000 (less than 3% of the combined results) and the top results are two Stack Exchange ELL pages (one is yours) asking the question if the phrase is right or wrong. So anything but the usual subject-verb agreement you would expect to find is very uncommon indeed.

Comment: Fear is a collection of fears? Fruit is a collection of fruits? Really?

Comment: @lambie No, you've completely misunderstood. It's not the fear or fruit that are generic, but the *spiders* and the *bananas*. Keep up. In the OP's example, 'locusts' is also a singular, generic noun

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153971/all-they-need-is-some-words-or-all-they-need-are-some-words/481677#481677

Comment: Your answer is a bit off the mark: (1) It does not address the [inversions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_copular_constructions) causing the confusion. (2) The "generic plural" reference is an irrelevant distraction; this is not the issue here. (3) You could also try to clear up the OP's confusion about the grammatical role of "the locusts", which is essential to understanding why this construction is difficult to analyze.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I don't address anything in other incorrect answers because that's not what one should do in an answer - I've used comments for that. I've just focused on the OP's question, and I've addressed it by showing that verb has to agree with the subject.

Comment: One of the reasons for the trouble in this and similar constructions is the divergence of the *numerus* between subject and predicate noun. That is unusual; Latin, for example, demands congruent predicate nouns: *Puer ambulat laetus / pueri ambulant laeti* (I hope my Latin didn't fail me here). In English this is usually maintained for nouns: "The waiters are all men", not "man". "These animals are tigers", not "tiger". But "The thing we have **is** locusts"!? And don't tell me "locusts" is not a plural ;-): "Locusts **are** flying insect**s**."

Comment: I didn't mean for you to address other answers but the reversion or reversibility of the construction -- it may not be clear that *thing* is the subject! --  as well as the confusion in the question (not in any answer, even though that can be helpful to clarify one's difference in opinion).

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica What I find odd is the refusal to deal with the reversals/inversions. Not that they are "in the sentence" but that are used **comparatively** to show that flexibility here. Comparison in linguistics is one of the few methods/techniques that most linguists agree on.

Comment: Why do you reckon "thing" is the subject? I'd argue this sentence is a simple re-ordering of the sentence "Locusts are the only thing we haven't seen", where "locusts" is clearly the subject.

Comment: @glibg10b I think that analysis is part of the question or problem here. I'm in no position to make that call (for example, I have not read nor do I own any of the quoted relevant grammar books). But let's just say that if you start a sentence with "The problem is..." there is little doubt about the subject.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica "Someone's at the door. Who is it?" "It's the plumbers." Or this: https://cosmology.carnegiescience.edu/timeline/1610/turtles-all-the-way-down.html

Comment: "The wages of sin is death." (Rom. 6:23, KJV).

Comment: @benwiggy aside from the KJV being written in early modern English and not at all comparable to modern English, "death" is something of an exception anyway because used this way it is a non-countable noun. The structure of the phrase focuses on the singular outcome for all people despite the plural nature of the 'wages'.

Comment: "my favorite fruit is the banana" would be perfectly acceptable... "the banana" being in this case a placeholder for "all bananas". I am sure there's a special word for that...

Comment: @Floris yes that would be a good alternative. But there's also a clear right and wrong in the OP's question.

Comment: Your Google search results turn up a lot of cases where "The only thing is" is followed by a *singular* noun, which isn't the case we're discussing here. [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+only+exception+are+those%2CThe+only+exception+is+those&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) suggests both are common with a plural noun, but admittedly the number of hits is low.

Comment: @alphabet the verb agreement is with the subject noun, which is "thing". And what follows ought to be a singular thing, but as my answer explains it can also be a generic or group noun and these can appear plural but are treated as singular. Ngrams have their place, but not here, because there are so many different constructions that could be made, you couldn't capture them all. Coincidentally, I've spent the day on an interview panel seeing candidates for a senior data analysis role. I didn't give the job to someone who used ngrams as an example of analysis, because they used them wrong, too.

Comment: @Astralbee While *thing* is singular, in certain contexts singular nouns can, or must, agree with plural verb forms. Compare: "A bunch of people were standing outside."

Comment: @alphabet that's an exception rather than contra-evidence. 'Bunch' is a very informal group term that emphasises the volume or formation of the people rather than collecting them together. In US English especially, it can just mean "a lot". So the verb agrees with 'people' because the emphasis remains on their individuality. If it was a more specific, recognisable 'bunch', more like a gang, you might say "*that bunch of people is back again*". And of course, you can have lots of non-count nouns too. As our US speakers might say, one of the answers on here is 'a bunch of crap'.

Comment: @Astralbee That's one exception. This case, the one in the OP's example, is another exception, as shown by the fact that a large number of native speakers use it and find it acceptable.

Answer (score 26):

Here is what real English speakers actually do. The examples (1)-(30) below show that in such cases native speakers, including some expert users of the language, often use plural *are* to agree with the **following** noun phrase.

The examples shown are from a range of sources [from the first page of a google search](https://tinyurl.com/mryvt29d), including world-famous film critics like [Roger Ebert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Ebert), the official promotional material for films, promotional blurb from publishers for books on Amazon and so forth.

What all of this shows is that with any kind of cleft-like sentence involving the word *thing*, you are quite likely to see the verb *BE* showing  ***proximity agreement*** with the noun phrase that follows it, instead of agreeing with the word *thing*.

It also shows that you should never **ever** listen to people when they try and change the rules of the language according to what **they** think the language should do!!!

Enjoy!:

---

#### Edit

Due to popular demand, I have now edited in a smaller sample of attested examples beginning *The only thing we saw **were***. These are taken from the texts of published books and academic journals.  This miniature corpus now occurs before the larger list below. Enjoy!

#### The only thing we saw were ...

1. *The only thing we saw were rocks*.
   Jorge Daniel Taillant (2021) [Meltdown: The Earth Without Glaciers](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Meltdown/P30_EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&pg=PA3&printsec=frontcover) The Open University Press
2. *The only thing we saw were thousands of sheep, raising dust.*
   Mark Harris, ‎Deborah Oppenheimer (2000) [Into the Arms of Strangers: Stories of the Kindertransport](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Into_the_Arms_of_Strangers/pwRbEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&pg=PA188&printsec=frontcover) Bloomsbury.
3. *The only thing we saw were granular deposits of IgG and complement.*
   José Strauss (2012) [Pediatric Nephrology: Volume 6 Current Concepts in Diagnosis and Management](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Pediatric_Nephrology/pX3cpjoEvdwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&printsec=frontcover) Springer.
4. *The only thing we saw were pictures they had taken of the scene and they were just from the head up.*
   James R. Acker, Robert M. Bohm and Charles S. Lanier [Editors]  (2014) [America's Experiment With Capital Punishment: Reflections on the Past, Present, and Future of the Ultimate Penal Sanction](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/America_s_Experiment_with_Capital_Punish/bjAFAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&printsec=frontcover) Carolina Academic Press
5. *The only thing we saw were numerous pinhead-size reddish purple spots, looking like raised tuffs of blood vessels in the periumbilical, pelvic, genital, and thigh areas.*
   Walter B. Shelley,  E. Dorinda Shelley (2006) [Consultations in Dermatology: Studies of Orphan and Unique Patients](https://books.google.co.uk/books?hl=en&lr=&id=NstpHJH4dl0C&oi=fnd&pg=PR11&dq=%22the+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&ots=TXVAjLoHbe&sig=1yHaMQLfVDJSrH3LVWoTP2O9_6k&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22the%20only%20thing%20we%20saw%20were%22&f=false) Cambridge University Press
6. *The only thing we saw were the final projects they shared at the end, which were also the only graded portions of the hidden writing assignment.*
   Salibrici, Mary M and Richard C Salter (2004) ["The Transitional Space of Hidden Writing: A Resource for Teaching Critical Insight and Concern."](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/55548) *Pedagogy*, **4**(2) p. 215-240. Project MUSE muse.jhu.edu/article/55548.
7. *The only thing we saw were wildly waving natives.*
   William Diebold (2012) [Hell is So Green: Search and Rescue Over the Hump in World War II](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Hell_Is_So_Green/NbtdppLfJ2AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&pg=PA16&printsec=frontcover) Lyons Press
8. *The only thing we saw were the helicopters.*
   Victoria Sandord (2000) [Buried Secrets: Truth and Human Rights in Guatemala](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Buried_Secrets/uv4gAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&printsec=frontcover) Palgrave Macmillan
9. *The only thing we saw were sea and sky and a number of sailboats, which made a beautiful sight on the water.*
   Norwegian-American Historical Association [Norwegain-American Studies](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Norwegian_American_Studies/J3UOAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&printsec=frontcover) Vol **24** p.35.
10. *The only thing we saw were sharks' fins sticking out of the water*
    Peter K. Lutken Jr. [author] & E. R. Lutken [editor] [A Thousand Places Left Behind: One Soldier’s Account of Jungle Warfare in WWII Burma](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/A_Thousand_Places_Left_Behind/L0a8EAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22The+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&pg=PT242&printsec=frontcover) University Press of Mississippi,

#### The only thing standing in his way ...

1. The only thing standing in his way **are** the heroes of The Justice Society.[See here](https://www.warnerbros.com/news/press-releases/black-adam-the-justice-society-files-arriving-july-5)
2. The only thing standing in his way **are** feelings for a girl he knows will hold him back from his dreams. [See here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pizza-Boys-Keith-Kelly/dp/B096TQ4RXB)
3. For Rams CB, E.J. Gaines, the only thing standing in his way **are** injuries. [See here](https://twitter.com/DowntownRams/status/774412370739355649)
4. The only thing standing in his way **are** Earth's mightiest heroes collectively known as the Avengers ... [See here](https://ronald-james-baculo.medium.com/was-thanos-right-e6e129185e9e)
5. The only thing standing in his way **are** those pesky workplace safety guidelines. [See here](https://www.instagram.com/deusexmachina.usa/p/CrRbQiSM6Y_/?img_index=1)
6. The only thing standing in his way **are** two U.S. fighter jets. [See here](https://www.reddit.com/r/whowouldwin/comments/11hrs8n/two_us_military_fighter_jets_vs_the_rumbling/?rdt=37738)
7. The only thing standing in his way **are** feral ponies, radical seniors, common sense, and Duncan's inability to do anything without a list. [See here](https://www.inkitt.com/stories/humor/964577)
8. The only thing standing in his way **are** Rylan, a jaded, half-breed thief from the forest where Faedryn’s body lays hidden, and Lorelei, a quirky, bright-eyed inquisitor who takes her orders from one of the empire’s five ruling quintarchs. [See here](https://www.goodreads.com/author/show/2851725.Bradley_P_Beaulieu/blog)
9. The only thing standing in his way **are** all the bugs, glitches and technical difficulties that come with any teleconference. [See here](https://geektyrant.com/news/avengers-age-of-technical-difficulties-comedic-fan-film)
10. The only thing standing in his way **are** two immigrants with massive mustaches who hope to throw a wrench in his plans. [See here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Kannabis-Kingdom-Herb-Highmen-ebook/dp/B07KK35PDL)
11. The only thing standing in his way **are** a travelling folk balladeer and centuries of history. [See here](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p04tlb1l)
12. A young man (Alexander) is ready to get his drivers license, and the only thing standing in his way **are** the outrageous, quirky and sometimes criminal driving test administrators he's paired with. [See here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6397330/)
13. The only thing standing in his way **are** his 6 older siblings. [See here](https://www.netgalley.com/book/312102/reviews)
14. The only thing standing in his way **are** a group of young students who have taken up the mantel of X-Men. [See here](https://955thefish.com/movies-and-dvds/theres-nothing-world-shaking-about-x-men-apocalypse)
15. The only thing standing in his way **are** the Avengers, led by Thor. [See here](https://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/avengers-infinity-war-2018)
16. The only thing standing in his way **are** feral ponies, radical seniors, common sense, and Duncan's inability to do anything without a list. [See here](https://www.longandshortreviews.com/book-reviews/small-stories-a-perfectly-absurd-novel-by-rob-roy-okeefe/)
17. Lil' Dice, on the other hand, wants nothing more than to be the favela's undisputed crime boss, and the only thing standing in his way **are** the older hoods. [See here](https://www.arkansasonline.com/news/2018/feb/09/city-of-god-2002-20180209/?print)
18. O'Toole will do anything to get his hands on this fabled coin, and the only thing standing in his way **are** a couple of kids in actual possession of the artifact [sic]: one of them's an American tourist, the other a Palestinian kid. [See here](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105361/reviews)
19. The only thing standing in his way **are** two American soldiers who believe they have discovered the target of the mission. [See here](https://www.hamiltonplace.com/products/product/orders-from-hitler-barnesnoble-ea67c5)
20. The only thing standing in his way **are** a dislocated wing, an order to fire Tulip from the hedonistic current CEO Hunter, and the baby. [See here](https://www.newindianexpress.com/entertainment/review/2016/Sep/23/storks-review-this-badass-animated-comedy-can-totally-work-for-both-parents-and-kids-1524257.html)
21. And the only thing standing in his way **are** those damn kids. [See here](https://www.pajiba.com/tv_reviews/recap-riverdale-is-awful-and-teetering-on-unsalvageable-.php)
22. The Devil has arrived to claim his bride-to-be, Courtney and the only thing standing in his way **are** the bridesmaids, some unlucky passerbys, and Glen and his ragtag bunch of groomsmen. [See here](https://mediamikes.com/2023/11/film-review-courtney-gets-possessed/)
23. Roshan has awaken to reclaim the AEGIS of Immortals and the only thing standing in his way **are** the Rotaractors! [See here](https://www.facebook.com/rotaractcolombomidtown/photos/roshan-has-awaken-to-reclaim-the-aegis-of-immortals-and-the-only-thing-standing-/2958702024208825/)
24. Really, the only thing standing in his way **are** outdated stereotypes and stigmas about women's football. [See here](https://www.chiesaditotti.com/2024/1/15/23675355/the-future-ex-roma-manager-power-poll-rock-bottom-edition)
25. He has an army of werewolves and dark plans for Germania and Francia, and the only thing standing in his way **are** the Centurions at Nordhaven. [See here](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Centurions_the_Werewolf_s_Gift.html?id=FDS-zQEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)
26. The only thing standing in his way **are** his legs. [See here](http://www.hotpress.co.nz/nz-film-awards.html)
27. The only thing standing in his way **are** people like Zeke and Kris, a vampire whose loyalty can't be bought. [See here](https://www.kpl.gov/catalog/item/?i=ent://ERC_215_8682/0/215_8682:HOOPLA:15404310)
28. The only thing standing in his way **are** the local yokels of Sommerton. [See here](https://bayweekly.com/the-last-stand/)
29. The only thing standing in his way **are** Republicans who must always remember that they have a mandate of their own—to stop him. [See here](https://www.maciverinstitute.com/2023/01/evers-is-finally-honest-about-his-agenda/)
30. The only thing standing in his way **are** a handful of corrupt officials and a culture not familiar with the problems facing their oceans. [See here](https://acepictures.com/project/current-sea/)

Comment: Oh, I posted an answer similar to yours.

Comment: +1 for "Here is what real English speakers actually do" I'm absolutely certain we hear this type of discordant singular subject and plural verb  **all the time** but when it sounds natural, and it will in a native speaker's voice, we don't notice the "mistake".

Comment: "expert users of the language often use plural are to agree with the following noun phrase."  It's more like everyday native speakers. Mine was the first answer to state that "are locusts" is okay, I gave the reversibility idea and yet I get no credit. And I even explained the grammar.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it could be strengthened by choosing examples with a broader variety of constructions, rather than only using “the only thing standing in X’s way [is/was ~ are/were]”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Only so much time in my lunch break, I'm afraid. There's hundreds of thousands  around. See here, for example: ["The only thing I don't like are"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22the+only+thing+I+don%27t+like+are%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#ip=1)

Comment: @Lambie Well, you got 7 upvotes, and one was from me! (Having said that I'm 50/50 about your reversible clause) Seems they needed lots of evidence. I'd call Roger Ebert an expert user. One of the most revered film critics ever!

Comment: Well, let's say film blurb writers are just expert *enough* to qualify as examples... this should indeed settle the question of "is it OK".

Comment: *All* of those sound wrong to this native speaker's ear.  I don't dispute that real native speakers sometimes make that mistake, but decent editors typically correct it in written English.  And I note that my usual correction would not be to change "are" to "is", but rather to change "thing" to "things".

Comment: In spoken English you can get away with all of these because "the only thing standing" and  "the only things standing" sound similar enough that a listener will hear whichever of these seems correct to them. As for *written* English, my main takeaway from this answer is that the Internet has enabled an explosion of unedited prose from inexpert writers.

Comment: Some of these examples are semi-illiterate even if you ignore the agreement of subject and verb. I might accept that "the heroes of the Justice Society" are "the only thing" in someone's way, since they collectively form a single, identifiable entity, but "feral ponies, radical seniors, common sense, and Duncan's inability to do anything without a list"? These cannot be "the only thing." These are four very different things. In this case the verb **are** is the only sensible choice because the subject **things** is the only sensible choice.

Comment: I mean a lot of native speakers also say things like "could of" etc. but that doesn't make right either.

Comment: @Sursula The proper pronunciation of both unstressed auxiliary *have* and unstressed *of* is /əv/. That's what people like the king of England say!

Comment: As David K points out, you can get away with this in spoken English.  The issue is not the speaker's failure to use the correct verb.  The issue is the speaker's failure to pluralize the first noun -- *the only thing[s]*.  The speaker is talking about many things as evidenced by the list.  It is difficult, however, to enunciate the words *things standing*.  Much easier to meld them into the singular.

Comment: @EllieK How about ["The only thing we saw were"](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22the+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)?

Comment: @Astralbee No, I just used one phrase  to collect a quarter of a million examples. I could have used many, many different ones. Try looking the one I made up for Mari-Lou A *The only thing we saw were* etc. They're all over the place and they exist because [The only thing + relative clause] is effectively a type of pseudo-cleft. And agreement in pseudo clefts (like the *all*-clefts in Lambie's answer) is well-known to often follow NP2 instead of NP1. I find your answer, which ignores the facts of what happens the language, far more bizarre!

Comment: It's interesting. To me, the "are" version *sounds* wrong, but as I point out in my comment under Astralbee's answer, [this Ngram suggests both are common,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=The+only+exception+are+those%2CThe+only+exception+is+those&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) though the number of hits is low.

Comment: @alphabet I'm currently adding some "the only thing we saw were" examples mainly from academic university presses and journals (or other reputable publishers)/ See what you think about those. Might be a few minutes.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't doubt that many others find those sentences perfectly acceptable in any register, and certainly some of your examples sound better than others. It seems like one of those cases where intuitions differ between native speakers.

Comment: @alphabet What do you think about those?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. For some reason, the ones with "The only thing we saw" sound much better to me.  But I suspect different speakers' intuitions will be all over the map.

Comment: @alphabet Might be because the examples are better, or as Mari-Lou says there's an intervening *we*, or summat.

Answer (score 14):

Very often in speech–less rarely in print–native speakers will instinctively prefer the plural form of the verb when it follows a plural pronoun (*we, they, you*) and the adjacent countable noun or noun phrase is plural,  even though the antecedent subject is singular.

From Google Books

> 1. The conduct of the police was beyond all praise, for they were unarmed. **The only thing** THEY had **were truncheons**, and there were very poor weapons for dealing with men firing Webley revolvers. No praise could be too high and no admiration too great for the way which the brave police officers have maintained the noble traditions of their force.
>    Source: *The Parliamentary Debates*: House of Lords official report (1941)

From a prescriptivist point of view, the grammatically correct version would be "The only **things** they had **were** truncheons…”

> 2. **The only thing** WE did not eat **were the butter and cream** because I knew that Brucellosis was still widespread in Britain. Never once in Britain did I knowingly eat or drink uncooked fresh British dairy products.
>    Source: *Oxford Angel*: The 91st General Hospital in World War II. (1966)

Similarly a prescriptivist might insist that the verb (*be*) agrees with the singular subject, i.e. "*The **only thing** we did not eat **was** the butter because I knew…*” which means the term *cream* has to be eliminated from the narrative or else we "must" pluralise the subject i.e. "…*the only **things** … **were** butter and cream*…”

> 3. Let me emphasize that **the one thing** WE did not have **were good, solid numbers**. We didn't have market data. It was a big guess. For instance if, if the market is for blue hula hoops and you're getting ready to sell red one with sequins and tassels, there isn't a market for your product;…
>    Source: *Workshop on Enzyme Economics*: (1975)
> 4. Any enquiry by the tax payers would have readily shown that the claims of value made by Jackie Fine Arts to the taxpayers before the first acquisitions were totally unsupported in fact and **the only thing** THEY bought **were** tax losses.
>    Source: *American Federal Tax Reports* (1989)
> 5. Last decade, our shining towers fell, our cities drowned, and our currency lost much of its value. Heavily armed soldiers patrolled our city streets during color-coded "terrorist" alerts. **About the only thing** WE didn't see ***were*** actual zombies
>    Source: *Horror Films FAQ* (2013) By John Kenneth Muir
> 6. **One thing** WE did not see **were patients with frontal lobe lesions**. Even though some of the research we will talk about had already taken place when I was in medical school in the early 1980s, the frontal lobes were still referred to as the silent lobes.
>    source: *Frontal Fatigue*
>    The Impact of Modern Life and Technology on Mental Illness (2021) By Dr. Mark Rego
> 7. The Banquet maître d' made an announcement at the end of the function to explain the situation and the game plan to get sleep, makeshift bed and washing stuff, towels etc. **The only thing** WE did not have **were toothbrushes**. Had there been a drugstore in the center…
>    Source: *tales* Trebbiano (2021)

Comment: +1 Nice post. I don't know the relative figures, but I do agree, intuitively,  that an intervening plural NP does indeed increase the chance of a plural verb.

Comment: I thought I'd try out your theory a bit and googled "[the only thing we saw **were**](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&sca_esv=ae27c76c7331fca2&rls=en&q=%22the+only+thing+we+saw+were%22&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiG2eK4r_6EAxWHT0EAHcWnDhYQBSgAegQIChAC&biw=1440&bih=797&dpr=2#ip=1). Tens of thousand of results.

Comment: Yes, a lot of examples, use of the word prescriptivist but no explanation as to why the verb is plural coming after phrases like "the only thing". I explained both the grammar and to boot cited an ELU answer.  Go figure...

Comment: @Lambie Please don't be bitter. Your answer was the first to say it's acceptable to use the plural verb "are" with a singular subject, and you got 7 upvotes and 7 downvotes. Your examples with **All you need are/were** are, in my eyes,  perfectly grammatical, I don't see a singular subject with a plural verb. I don't think why OP's sentence the plural verb is in fact an example of inverse copular construction. *John, Peter and Sam **are** the plumbers*. Would you use *is* here?

Comment: Some would argue that "Locusts are the only thing we haven't seen.” should instead be “*Locusts are the only* **things** *we haven't seen*.” Unlike the examples you cited from Wikipedia, I found examples that are similar to the OP's sentence. And, you may disagree, but I did attempt to explain the construction.

Comment: @Lambie [**All** is more often used with **plural** verb forms, though sometimes it is used with **singular** verbs. This happens when we are referring to *all* as a totality of items under consideration. …:](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv266.shtml#:~:text=All%20is%20more%20often%20used,Is%20all%20well%20with%20you%3F) and further: **Have all** (of) the **presents** been distributed?
**All** (of) my **friends have come** to my party.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What you say about the plumbers is not the point. No, I would use the plural verb and my whole point is **why one can do that** in similar sentences and in the OP's sentence AND in mine that I thought up. Also, bear in mind that "*The only thing* we haven't seen" is a set phrase and it is not like: "The only things we haven't seen".  For the inverse copular construction you keep the verb as is. The boy is the guilty party. The guilty party is the boy. For a singular example [haha]. Right now: I have zero upvotes. Zero. So, I am somewhat miffed. :)

Comment: @Lambie I didn't upvote because (1) your quotes are all with "all" which moves the goal posts because "all" can arguably be considered a plural ("All are healthy"); (2) You simply quote Wikipedia with examples that do not apply because they are singular/singular cases; and you quote without comment which is insufficient; (3) The post is poorly edited; (4) You do not actually present an argument, a conclusion or an answer!

Comment: Good point that the plural pronoun may make the plural verb more likely!

Comment: This seems to happen only a) in a copular construction b) with a plural complement and c) a relative clause coming between the subject and the verb d) which itself has a plural subject. Thus, "the only thing (that; RC) we (pl. RC s.) didn't see _were_ (cop.) actual zombies (pl. comp.)." is fine, but "the only thing (that; RC) we (pl. RC s.) have to fear _is_ (cop.) fear itself (sing. comp.)." But also, I feel strongly that "The only thing _I_ didn't see were actual zombies" is wrong. So I think it's a combination of the plural RC subject and the plural matrix complement that triggers this.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I give my readers the chance to understand that A=B and B=A are the same thing. And the copular in those are the equal signs.

Answer (score 6):

> The only thing we haven't seen are locusts.

You are right that we should use *is* as the subject *the only thing* is singular.  The noun *locusts*, however, is not the object; it's the subject complement.   Copulas are intransitive.

Comment: Do you mean both "IS" and "ARE" correct?

Comment: @Yunus - only 'is' is correct. You could say or write 'The only things we haven't seen are locusts'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

"The only thing we haven't seen are locusts."

Locusts are the only thing we haven't seen.

Other examples:

- All we need for the party are clams.
- Clams are all we need for the party.

- All you told me were lies.
- Lies are all you told me.

And some examples from [all we need is and all we need are](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153971/all-they-need-is-some-words-or-all-they-need-are-some-words/481677#481677):

- All we need are a few symbols here and there.
- All we need are words like 'reason' and 'evidence'.
- All we need are the numbers.

See the full ELU answer.

Wikipedia

> In linguistics, **inverse copular constructions**, named after Moro
> (1997), are a type of inversion in English where canonical SCP word
> order (subject-copula-predicative expression, e.g. Fred is the
> plumber) is reversed in a sense, so that *one appears to have the
> order PCS instead (predicative expression-copula-subject, e.g. The
> plumber is Fred).* The verb in these constructions is always the
> copula be (am, are, is, was, were). *Inverse copular constructions are
> intriguing because they render the distinction between subject and
> predicative expression difficult to maintain*. The confusion has led
> to focused study of these constructions,[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_copular_constructions) and their impact on the
> theory of grammar may be great since they appear to *challenge the
> initial binary division of the sentence (S) into a subject noun phrase
> (NP) and a predicate verb phrase (VP) (S → NP VP),* this division
> being at the core of all phrase structure grammars (as opposed to
> dependency grammars, which do not acknowledge the binary division).
>
> Inverse copular constructions involve nouns and noun phrases, but they
> do not allow the post-copula nominal to be a personal pronoun:
>
> a. The cause of the riot is a picture on the wall.
> b. A picture on thewall is the cause of the riot. - Inverse copular construction
> c. *A picture on the wall is it. - Post-verb subject cannot be a personal
> pronoun.
> a. Fred is the plumber.
> b. The plumber is Fred. - Inverse
> copular construction
> c. *The plumber is he. - Post-verb subject cannot
> be a personal pronoun.
>
> The defining trait of the inverse copular
> constructions is that two counts of inversion appear to have occurred:
> the normal subject has inverted to a post-verb position, and the
> predicative nominal has inverted to the pre-verb position. The verb is
> a finite form of the copula 'be' (am, are, is, was, were). This type
> of inversion is generally NOT possible with other verbs.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_copular_constructions)

Comment: This answer is totally wrong.

Comment: @Astralbee Is it? Why? I'm not an English grammarian but the logic in this answer appears sound, and the quote correct.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The "logic" seems to be that, if you completely rewrite the sentence and reverse the subject and predicate nominative you can use 'are', therefore that must be correct for the original sentence, too. That's not logic - that's proving that 2+2=5. Have you read my answer - the one with the highest number of upvotes?

Comment: @Astralbee Well, arguably you do not "completely rewrite the sentence" but revert " two counts of inversion" (Wikipedia) in PCS to restore the standard order of an English sentence. Once the standard order SCP is established, it is evident that the formal subject is a plural which would require a plural verb. If we believe the Wikipedia article (which must be correct -- I have written it only yesterday! ;-) ), Englieh grammar requires that "the copula agrees with the singular predicative expression to its left as opposed to with the plural subject to its right"...

Comment: @Astralbee ... but that's not as clear-cut as you make it. The actual subject retreats to the background so much that the predicative expression takes on its role and topples entire grammar theories. As a German native speaker, I feel a certain grammatical tension with "the problem is the teachers", and I'm not perfectly sure whether the copula cannot be kept congruent with the actual subject on occasion. But then English (also: *which* English!?) is confused about singular and plural to begin with ("the police are here", but "the United States is a country").

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica The Wikipedia entry has been grossly misquoted, because it speaks about other languages as well as English. The relevant point from the entry is "*In the inverse copular constructions, the copula agrees with the singular predicative expression to its left as opposed to with the plural subject to its right. This phenomenon seems to be limited to English"*. In English, the subject-verb agreement is required.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well said ;-). Alas, I understand Astralbee's argument and exasperation better now, I think: "thing" is indeed the subject here, and not a predicative expression in an unusual position, as I perceived it originally. I like BillJ's insistence in the comments that the construction is "reversible", not actually "reversed". But it is close, as other languages show, and possibly can be interpreted in the "German" way as an actual reversion, retaining the plural verb form congruent with the plural subject which just happens to be trailing.

Comment: @Peter Yes, _thing_ is undoubtedly the subject. But as described in [CoolHandLouis’ answer to the related question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/29170) and [linguisticturn’s on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/481677), that doesn’t necessarily matter in this particular construction. There are few cases where going with straight-up subject–verb agreement would sound wrong, but there are enough cases where proximity agreement _doesn’t_ sound wrong that blanket statements that subject–verb agreement is the only option cannot be upheld.

Comment: @Astralbee Exactly what Janus said x 5.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet When you say that English speakers "naturally produce forms like the one quoted", are you saying that you acknowledge it is wrong, but people say it anyway? Yes, native speakers make mistakes in their own language, especially when speaking extemporaneously. Most people begin a sentence without knowing exactly how it is going to end, and that's why there isn't always subject-verb agreement. But this isn't a site for teaching people how to make mistakes - it's a site for teaching the *correct* grammar.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I don't normally respond to people who aren't there so you can just read what I replied to Janus.

Comment: I wonder if anybody bothered with: "All we need for the party **are clams**. Clams **are** all we need for the party." Would: "All we need for the party **is** clams." be a) equally acceptable? or b) unacceptable? The literature (which I seem to have misplaced from the Internet) seems to think both are acceptable. That said, if **are** is acceptable, why isn't my explanation valid?? [two question marks just means very surprised.]

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet and Astralbee - Thought we could do with seeing what people do in real life. See my post!

Comment: @Astralbee This: "The "logic" seems to be that, if you completely rewrite the sentence and reverse the subject and predicate nominative you can use 'are', therefore that must be correct for the original sentence, too. is not true." All we need for the party are clams is reversed in: Clams are all we need for the party. The Subject and Complement are reversed, but there is no **complete rewriting**. Also, the examples are contrastive. Neither sentence is a reversal of the other until one shows that to be the case for these types of copulars. And I did not misquote the article.

Comment: @Astralbee No, I am saying that native speakers naturally say this all the time, with absolutely no notion that it is ‘wrong’, and **this by definition makes it not wrong**. It is not a mistake, but a very common and easily reproducible part of English grammar. To claim that it is wrong is akin to saying that it’s ‘wrong’ to end a sentence with a preposition, despite the fact that native speakers do it all the time. Yes, people make mistakes in their own languages; this just isn’t one of them.

Comment: Using "things...are locusts" would imply that there are many individual things one hasn't seen, all of which are locusts, and would not imply anything about whether there might exist locusts that one *has* seen.  Using "thing...is" would imply that "locusts" is a singular *category* of things one hasn't seen.  Using "thing...are" may not fit normal grammar, but conveys a notion that "locusts" shifted from referring to an abstract category when the speaker began the sentence, to referring to the insects that were observed before the speaker finished.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica 'I feel a certain grammatical tension with "the problem is the teachers"' - I read that and had a flashback to Jeff Wayne's musical adaptation of _War of the Worlds_, in which the Martians discuss colonising Earth. One of them says 'The problem is the humans', in a sort of Dalek voice. Of course, one would not expect Martians to be expert grammarians.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question regarding why "The only thing" is followed by "are":

The most likely explanation is that the speaker simply preferred to express it in that manner, and the statement was directly quoted by the reporter. There likely isn't a deeper reason beyond the speaker's preference.

As a native speaker, I also tried saying the sentence with both "are" and "is" to gauge how each felt to me. I believe "are" sounds better because it creates a smoother rhythm in the sentence. Almost like it's a haiku.

Read this out-loud like it's a poem.

> The only thing

> We haven't seen

> Are locusts

When speaking, the rules serve as guidelines. If our speech sounds okay and the meaning is conveyed, it's generally acceptable. The only real-world situations I've encountered where strict adherence to rules matters are when the writing is intended for widespread publication, is a formal document like a resume or contract, or is a school assignment.